# How to get IP Address from IIS Bindings

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to fetch IP address from IIS bindings

[image]

I am using below code :-

```
using (ServerManager iisServerManager = new ServerManager())
                {
                    foreach (Site site in iisServerManager.Sites)
                    {
                        foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
                        {
                             ipAddress = binding.EndPoint.Address.Address.ToString();

                        }


                    }
                }
```

But at foreach loop of iisServerManager.Sites , It is throwing exception ,

```
{"Filename: redirection.config\r\nError: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions\r\n\r\n"}
```

To Make this working , I tried :-

1. Running visual studio as administrator
2. Giving full rights to the path of file redirect.config

Please help me how can I resolve this?